# Compare two vector

Tags: java, vector, compare

I have two Vector just like below;

```
private Vector<Vector<Object>> vector1 = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
private Vector<Vector<Object>> vector2 = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
```

Some methods fill above vectors and created Vectors are;

vector1

```
[1000, 0, 100100, 1]
[1000, 1, 100100, 1]
[1000, 2, 100100, 1]
[1000, 3, 100100, 1]
```

vector 2

```
[1000, 0, ppp, yyy]
[1000, 1, zzz, xxx]
```

As you can see vector 2 less two row. Vector's 0th and 1st columns important for me. I use them in sql query. I need delete vector 1 releated columns from DB when rows not in vector 2.

My code is:

```
for(int i =0; i != vector1.size(); i++){
        if (i>vector2.size()){
            System.out.println("detected");
            try{
             ResultSet rs;
             Statement stmt;
             ResultSetMetaData rsmtd;
             String query = "USE DBST\n" +
             "delete from Mtable where   Me='"+vector1.elementAt(i).elementAt(0).toString()+"' and P='"+vector1.elementAt(i).elementAt(1).toString()+"'";
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.130.100;" + "databaseName=DBST;" + "user=" + "user1" + ";" + "password=" + "user1pass" + ";"; 
             Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
             stmt = con.createStatement();
             rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            }
            catch(SQLException se){
            se.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
           System.out.println(vector1.elementAt(i).elementAt(0).toString()+vector1.elementAt(i).elementAt(1).toString());
        }

    }
```

When i run this code nothing happened. Surplus rows (2nd and 3rd row of vector 1) not deleted from DB. Always come else statement and print desired format of current vector1 row.

How can I handle this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `[1000, 0, ppp, yyy]`? is `ppp` a number too?

Comment: You are deleting the record from database... but where are you refreshing the vector contents?

Comment: It is Vector column values. ppp is a string not necessary. I use only 0 and 1 column of Vector for matching.

Comment: Did you check for exceptions? What happens when you execute the query which is created in that loop manually? Oh and btw, even if you delete the rows from the _database_ the vectors in the _code_ would still have them until you reinitialize the vectors.

Comment: I don't think you should organize the code that way, with a single loop with everything inside. I think you should divide your code in phases and do just one thing in each one. At least one to detect the differences between vectors and take note of them and one to connect db, apply the changes and disconnect. That way is a lot easier to debug.

Comment: @Thomas Query working in DB without exception. I create these two vector before begin this for loop. ACtually Vectors are static.

Comment: One another note: loop never enter if condition. Because i never see "detected" in debug screen.

Comment: Well, if the loop never enters the condition then that explains why the entries are not deleted ;) - Did you debug your code?

Comment: Yes i do. But nothing useful in debug. Only i see loop not enter to if condition :) loop end with else and gui appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the comparison goes, you can do the following to compare the 1st and 2nd entries in each vector, and then toss out the vector that is not found from the DB.

```
List<ArrayList<Integer>> vector1 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
List<ArrayList<Integer>> vector2 = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tmp.add(1000);
tmp.add(0);
tmp.add(100100);
tmp.add(1);
vector1.add(tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tmp.add(1000);
tmp.add(1);
tmp.add(100100);
tmp.add(1);
vector1.add(tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tmp.add(1002);
tmp.add(2);
tmp.add(100100);
tmp.add(1);
vector1.add(tmp);

tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tmp.add(1000);
tmp.add(0);
tmp.add(100102);
tmp.add(2);
vector2.add(tmp);
tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
tmp.add(1000);
tmp.add(1);
tmp.add(100100);
tmp.add(1);
vector2.add(tmp);

System.out.println(vector1);
System.out.println(vector2);

Integer[] vec3 = new Integer[2];
Integer[] vec4 = new Integer[2];
boolean flag = false;

for (ArrayList<Integer> vec1Tmp : vector1) {
    flag = false;
    vec3[0] = vec1Tmp.get(0);
    vec3[1] = vec1Tmp.get(1);

    for (ArrayList<Integer> vec2Tmp : vector2) {
        vec4[0] = vec2Tmp.get(0);
        vec4[1] = vec2Tmp.get(1);

        if ( Arrays.equals(vec3, vec4) ) {
            flag = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    if ( !flag ) {
        // do your deletion here
        System.out.println(vec1Tmp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to answer. Itsl looks like useful. When i go home i can try it and inform you.

Comment: Do you offer manually define vectors? If it is i can't do it. Because my vector1 & vector2 filled automaticly from DB before the loop begins.

Comment: my `vec1` and `vec2` are just examples of two vectors. You have two vectors called `vector1` and `vector2`. Just replace those in the sample code above. The rest should work. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, do you get a bunch of vectors stored somewhere? Or do they come in the process (one by one) as they become available?

Comment: Sorry sometimes my eglish not enough understand what you asking exactly. BTW: My vectors are object and java says vectorObject not converted to Integer for your code.

Comment: You should avoid using `Vector` .. this is a very deprecated java collection.  Use `List` and `ArrayList`. I have given you an example above. It should do exactly what you need.

Comment: I try it. But i love Vectors :( Very hard for me leaving from it :(

Comment: The concept is the same.. `ArrayList` is much more efficient. Please try and let me know.

Comment: Ok i can try it but i must change my methods etc. Because my methods too create vectors. BTW: Arraylist shows per column in new line i think. Vectors keep it in one row. Is it problem ?

Comment: Awesome .. don't forget the thumbs up for the solution! ty

Comment: And my columns not have only integer values. This is problem i think.

Comment: Actually vector1 4 columns is my db tables 4 columns. column0:"1000" but sql table shows is varchar. column1:"0" sql table shows int. column 2:"100100" sql table shows varchar. column 3:"1" sql table shows bit. I love Vectors because automaticly identify them.

Comment: Then instead of `Integer` choose `Object` in the `ArrayList` type.

Comment: If we can loop it as Vectors and detect surplus columns i can handle it. Edit: Ok i can try with Object type.

Comment: It works succesfully. Sometimes vector2 has surplus row and i can reverse this loop and add some rows to another table.